# Always make a square symmetric data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to create a function that takes a data frame and makes it a square, symmetric data frame such that if the number of rows exceeds the number of columns, drop the first x number of rows such that the number of rows equals the number of columns (I have to do this vice-versa too).

For example, I need:

```
> df   
     a  b  c
  a  1  2  3 
  b  4  5  6
```

to look like:

```
> df   
     b  c
  a  2  3 
  b  5  6
```

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise. What have you tried? Do you know how to write a function? Do you know how to get the number of rows or columns from a data frame? Do you know how to find the minimum of two numbers? From this question it's not clear what part you are stuck on.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "symmetric"? By the usual definition of what a symmetric matrix is, your example is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach.

```
myfunction <- function (v) v[(nrow(v)-min(nrow(v),ncol(v))+1):nrow(v),(ncol(v)-min(nrow(v),ncol(v))+1):ncol(v)]
```

**DATA**

```
> df <- matrix(1:12,c(3,4))
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

**TEST**

```
> myfunction(df)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    7   10
[2,]    5    8   11
[3,]    6    9   12
```